# Print images of canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, printing

I'm having a little issue with printing `canvas` `elements` using `onClick` and a `javascript` `function` to print the `canvas` `elements` on two pages within the same print job.

Right now I'm using `jsPDF` to create downloadable PDF's for the user to save.  This is working as intended.

I also want to create a print feature that prints each `canvas` as a page.

Using the `autoprint` feature in `jsPDF` looked like an obvious answer, but unfortunately I've only been able to get it to spit out the `canvas` pages in portrait format jammed together on the same page. I want to print these `canvas` `elements` in landscape with each printed on it own page, but within the same print job.

I've looked around a bit at other `javascript` solutions for printing images, but those all assume an external source for the image.  I need a solution like that, only pointing to the `toDataURL()` that I've already created.

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere before, but so far I haven't been able to piece it together correctly.

Here's what I've cobbled together for the `jsPDF` which spits out the portrait format listed above that I don't want.

```
function print() {
    ctx1.drawImage(c2,0,0); 
    ctx1.drawImage(c3,0,0); 
    var imgData1 = planner1.toDataURL(); 
    var imgData2 = planner2.toDataURL(); 
    var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'letter');
    pdf.addImage(imgData1, 'PNG', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'IMG1', 'fast');
    pdf.addPage();
    pdf.addImage(imgData2, 'PNG', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'IMG2', 'fast');
    pdf.autoPrint();
}‌‌‌‌‌‌
```

If anyone knows how to manipulate `autoPrint()` to support different sizes and formats, I'd love to hear about it since `jsPDF` documentation is a bit wanting.

Otherwise, I'd go for creating two letter sized `png` images that can be printed in the same print job as the other option.

I'd be eternally grateful for any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well jsPDF wasn't going to get it done so I went the `png` route.  Not exactly the most elegant solution (would have preferred to not to have to open another window and then close it) but it prints exactly what I want....

```
<script>
function print() {

  ctx1.drawImage(c2,0,0);
  ctx1.drawImage(c3,0,0);

  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write("<img src='"+planner1.toDataURL()+"'/><img src='"+planner2.toDataURL()+"'/>");
  win.print();
  win.window.close();

  window.location.href = '../php/planner.php?pln=<?php echo $user ?>';
}
</script>
```

I also added some `css` to ensure the headers and footers don't print.